# How to go through PHP array return from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, group-by

I have run a SQL query that has a group by of "province and gender", the result is following array:

```
Array ( [province] => Helmand [gender] => Male [ppl] => 1110 ) 
Array ( [province] => Kandahar [gender] => Male [ppl] => 898 ) 
Array ( [province] => Uruzgan [gender] => Male [ppl] => 44 ) 
Array ( [province] => Zabul [gender] => Male [ppl] => 248 )
```

I know it has 4 provinces, but i assume the list is not fixed, so using anything like Switch how can i go through this array and pick the desired results.

*for example: how many female are there in Helmand.*

Comment: update your question and add the code that you use for obtain this array

Answer (score 0):

you could add to new array

example :

```
$new_data = array();
foreach($list_data as $key => $val)
{
    $new_data[$val->province][$val->gender] = $val->ppl;
}
```

in your next step you can do anything with the array for example :

```
$result = '';
if(isset($new_data['Helmand']['Female']))
{
   // here is the next step to access it through new assosiative array
   $result = $new_data['Helmand']['Female'];
}
```

Good luck

Comment: Hi,
It gives me following error:


Notice: Undefined variable: list_data in C:\xampp\htdocs\management\inds\1.1\1.1.php on line 47

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\management\inds\1.1\1.1.php on line 47

Comment: bro , list_data should be the result of your array. its just example variable from me.